# iText error in signing big PDF files: SigDict /Contents illegal data

Tags: java, pdf, itext, signature

I am trying to sign a lot of PDF files using iText (latest version) for Java. But I have problem with big ones. With files with size over 30 MByte (until 120 MByte) I get a signature non valid error in the Acrobat Reader (and other readers) with this message: **SigDict / Contents illegal data**

The same code works well for other files with size < 30 MByte. Here is the code I use:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore_path), keystore_password.toCharArray());
String alias = prop.getProperty("key.alias");
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias , key_password.toCharArray());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileIn.getPath(), ownerpassword);          
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, new FileOutputStream(fileOut),  '\0', null , true);                         
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setCrypto(pk, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sign.field.start.x")),
                    Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sign.field.start.y")),
                    Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sign.field.end.x")), 
                    Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sign.field.end.y")));
appearance.setReason(prop.getProperty("sign.field.reason"));
appearance.setLocation(prop.getProperty("sign.field.location"));
appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sign.field.page")), "SignField");            

stamper.close();
```

---- UPDATE ----

It seems a problem related to a bug of iText (at least 5.2.1) for Java.

See this post: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/iText-error-in-signing-big-PDF-files-SigDict-Contents-illegal-data-td4655309.html#none

I leave the post opened for everyone that has this kind of problem.

Comment: no one on this topic? mhhh...

Comment: It seems a problem of iText 5.2.1. I update the post.